# Getting Facebook Authenticated Referrals from "Likes"

Tags: authentication, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

We're trying to use the Facebook [Authenticated Referrals](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/authentication/#referrals) feature on our website.

Right now it works fine when one user (Alice) uses a Feed Dialog to post to her wall and another user (Bob) clicks on Alice's post. Bob sees an Auth Dialog before navigating to our website.

But our app doesn't (currently) use Feed Dialogs; we just have Like buttons everywhere. I was hoping/expecting that when Alice clicks the Like button in an article on our site, and Bob clicks on Alice's "Like" post, Bob would get an Auth Dialog.

Am I just misconfiguring my site/app somehow? Is it possible to get Authenticated Referrals from Likes at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a [Facebook bug](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/196428150454557), a FB engineer responded to say: "this is currently the design of authenticated referrals. It only happens with Open Graph app publishes."

So, at least for now, no authenticated referrals are possible for Facebook Like links.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't realise this was potentially possible - I assumed it would work if the liked URLs were all http://apps.facebook.com/{YOUR NAMESPACE}/ URLs - if this isn't working it sounds like either a bug or a fairly reasonable feature request.

If the likes are to URLs outside of your Canvas URL I wouldn't really expect this to work, because the links are not definitely associated with your canvas app

Answer (score 0):

«If you need access to more information, such as the user's email address, etc. you must request permissions for this information. If you can do this by adding the permissions you need to the scope attribute of the Login Button like below»

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/

Check the link, I've waste enough time but still not understand, why should we ask grant permission for our application twice — in App Settings first and `<div class="fb-login-button" data-scope="read_stram, offline_access">` here is the second one. Just check your **data-scope** attribute.

`<fb:login-button>` attribute is `scope`, you can read a bit about it by the link below.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/login/